# Why can't I query an element that I just added via append()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why can't I query an element that I just added via append()?

```
$('body').append('<div id="testing"></div>');
if($("#testing").length == 0)
    alert("WTF!  Testing div should be there!");
```

Is there some kind of layout that doesn't happen until the JS finishes running or something?

How can I get around this?  Is there some other method that I could call to create dom elements to work with right away?

Comment: Works fine for me... http://jsfiddle.net/8zMPZ/

Comment: Where are your running this code? Is the `<body>` element ready yet? This should be run in `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would look as to where this code is being executed.  Is this being run with a jQuery(document).ready() function block?   I can't see your full code.

When I run into stuff like this, it's usually because my code is executing before the dom is ready.  Please try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').append('<div id="testing"></div>');
    if($("#testing").length == 0){
        alert("WTF!  Testing div should be there!");
    }
});
```

Comment: Yep.  That was absolutely the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Because the length of `#testing` is 1. As shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/Skooljester/FrsHs/2/

Comment: Your jsFiddle doesn't use `.append()` to create an element and then check to see if it's there

Comment: @MrOBrian Gives the same result... Please see the updated fiddle.

Comment: But his issue wasn't that `.length` was returning 1, his code was saying that if `.length` is 0 then "wtf? it SHOULD be there but it isn't".  The problem the OP was having is that the div wasn't being added, not that he was checking for the wrong length

Comment: @MrOBrian I completely misread that, whoops =/ Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/9ucYA/1/)*

```
$(function(){

    if( $("#testing").length  ){   // test for existance               
            alert("YEEE there it is!");                
    }else{                 
             alert("Buuuubububu :( ");            
    }

});
```

if you **test for non existence** use:

```
if( $("#testing").length <= 0  )
```

or:

```
if( !($("#testing").length)  )
```